# Rendering SVG with no container in Plastiq

Tags: javascript, plastiq

I'm using [Plastiq](http://www.featurist.co.uk/plastiq/) to create a simple icon component that renders SVG:

```
module.exports = function(icon) {
  return h.rawHtml('.icon',
    '<svg><use xlink:href="#i-' + icon + '"></use></svg>'
  );
}
```

I'm using [rawHtml](https://github.com/featurist/plastiq#raw-html) since SVG isn't supported yet. This returns the HTML:

```
<div class="icon">
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#i-example"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I would prefer the HTML:

```
<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#i-example"></use>
</svg>
```

But this doesn't work:

```
module.exports = function(icon) {
  return h.rawHtml('<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#i-' + icon + '"></use></svg>');
}
```

Nor does this:

```
module.exports = function(icon) {
  return h.rawHtml('svg.icon',
    '<use xlink:href="#i-' + icon + '"></use>'
  );
}
```

Or this:

```
module.exports = function(icon) {
  return h('svg.icon',
    h.rawHtml('<use xlink:href="#i-' + icon + '"></use>')
  );
}
```

Looks like rawHtml requires an element selector Plastiq has support for? Is there a recommended approach for this?